# Binding does not work between view and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I just started to develop in Mean.js and have a bit of problem on angular part.

Ive created api in node which can do basic crud with recipe model.

Now Im trying to display a list of existing recipes.

Controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('recipe').controller('RecipeController', ['$scope', 'RecipeService',
  function ($scope, RecipeService) {
    // Recipe controller logic
    var vm = this;

    vm.recipes = RecipeService.query();
  }
]);
```

View:

```
<section data-ng-controller="RecipeController">
  <div data-ng-repeat="recipe in vm.recipes">
    {{recipe.title}}
  </div>
</section>
```

Service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('recipe').factory('RecipeService', [ '$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    // Recipe service logic
    var Recipe = $resource('api/recipes/:recipeId', {
      recipeId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });

    angular.extend(Recipe.prototype, {
      createOrUpdate: function () {
        var recipe = this;
        return createOrUpdate(recipe);
      }
    });

    function createOrUpdate(recipe) {
      if(recipe._id) {
        return recipe.$update(onSuccess, onError);
      } else {
        return recipe.$save(onSuccess, onError);
      }

      function onSuccess(recipe) {

      }

      function onError(errorResponse) {
        var error = errorResponse.data;
        handleError(error);
      }
    }

    function handleError(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    // Public API
    return Recipe;
  }
]);
```

So, when I console log the vm.recipe in controller and then take a look after async call will handle stuff, I will see 2 results in vm.recipes, which is correct since I have 2 results in the DB. This kinds of proves that service is working fine and load the data. Also, it looks like in controller its okay, since it will retrieve data there. But, those data will not be loaded into view, and I have no idea why. The view is selected correctly in the config.

Have anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, did not find out why it does not work in this form, but Ive been able to get it working by simply putting recipes into $scope property.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('recipe').controller('RecipeController', ['$scope', 'RecipeService',
  function ($scope, RecipeService) {
    // Recipe controller logic
    $scope.recipes = RecipeService.query();
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this

at the place of

```
var vm = this;

vm.recipes = RecipeService.query();
```

try to use

```
$scope.recipes = RecipeService.query();
```

in controller

and in html
at place of

use

only

Comment: We were both right. I actually find ut why this vm example did not work and it did in mean.js example module. There was some flag to set up mapping of scope as vm property.

Comment: @MichalTakáč Are you referring to the `controllerAs: 'vm'` in the `client.routes.js` file ?

Comment: @LukeKroon No I was not and that was the mistake.